# I want to retrieve Map object using common digester

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

I have a xml as below.

```
<list>
    <map>
    <map name="CLAIM_TICKET_1">
    <val name="CLAIM_TICKET_Groups">Kalyan</val>
    <val name="Testing">Ram</val>
    </map>
    <map name="CLAIM_TICKET_2">
    <val name="CLAIM_TICKET_Groups">Raju</val>
    <val name="Testing">Varma</val>
    </map>
    </list>
```

I trying to retrieve that as Map object using digester.

I want output as:

As list of Map objects.

```
{CLAIM_TICKET_1={CLAIM_TICKET_Groups=Kalyan,Testing=Ram},
CLAIM_TICKET_2={CLAIM_TICKET_Groups=Raju,Testing=Varma}}
```

My Code shows error:

String Xpath = "map/map";

```
digester.addObjectCreate(Xpath, HashMap.class);
    digester.addCallMethod(Xpath , "put", 2);
    digester.addCallParam(Xpath, 0, "name");        

    digester.addObjectCreate(Xpath, HashMap.class);
    digester.addCallMethod(Xpath+"/val" , "put", 2);
    digester.addCallParam(Xpath+"/val", 0, "name");        
    digester.addCallParam(Xpath+"/val", 1);

    digester.addSetNext(Xpath+"/val", "put");
```

Comment: Could you please indent your XML and your Java code? That would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String Xpath = "map/map";
//For every occurence of list/map add map object to list object
    digester.addObjectCreate("list/map", ArrayList.class);

    digester.addObjectCreate(Xpath, HashMap.class);
    digester.addCallMethod(Xpath+"/val" , "put", 2);
    digester.addCallParam(Xpath+"/val", 0, "name");        
    digester.addCallParam(Xpath+"/val", 1);

digester.addSetNext("list/map", "add"); 


It works fine.
```